# PostgreSQL On Ubuntu stopped responding and failed to Start

Tags: postgresql

I'm on Ubuntu machine. Postgresql stopped responding today morning. And the process was in idle state. When I executed restart script the output I get -

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-8.4 restart
    * Starting PostgreSQL 8.4 database server
    * Removed stale pid file.
    Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/8.4/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf"
```

Can you guide where should I look for the exact reason for this failure. Most Imp. - How to start the server now.

Comment: What does the log file /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log say?